# Should I fail "The Tavern" encounter to get the token?

Tags: hand-of-fate

I've gotten this encounter twice now, where the captain says his ship (the Wench) is being held captive by pirates. I agree to help, and am faced with a four-card roll, including success, huge success, failure, and huge failure.

I have gotten huge success, and the captain says whoops, he accidentally forgot where it was parked because he was drunk, no pirates involved, and I got a gain card (maybe 2?). I've gotten regular success, and the ship is just abandoned when I arrive at the pier, and I get a gain card.

However, neither of these scenarios gets me the token for the encounter.

If neither success rolls get me a token, do I just need to fail and fight? Or is there some other restriction, like succeeding on a huge failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Hand of Fate wiki](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/The_Tavern) has details on this encounter, but the short answer is, yes; this encounter has a bunch of branches, and the only one that results in the token is Failure -> Huge Success -> "Attack the Captain".